# Implementing Index for type with a lifetime parameter

Tags: rust, lifetime

I have some types like this, where they each have a lifetime parameter.

```rust
use std::marker::PhantomData;
use std::ops::Index;

pub struct Foo<'ctx> {
    bars: Vec<Bar<'ctx>>,
    phantom: PhantomData<&'ctx ()>,
}

impl Foo<'_> {
    pub fn get_bar(&self, index: usize) -> Option<&Bar> {
        self.bars.get(index)
    }
}

pub struct Bar<'ctx> {
    // pretend we are using a context here
    phantom: PhantomData<&'ctx ()>,
}
```

I'd like to implement `Index` for `Foo`, but the compiler doesn't like it:

```rust
impl <'ctx> Index<usize> for Foo<'ctx> {
    type Output = Bar<'ctx>;

    fn index(&self, _index: usize) -> &Self::Output {
        self.get_bar(_index).unwrap()
    }
}
```

I get this error:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for autoref due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/ir/foo.rs:24:14
   |
24 |         self.get_bar(_index).unwrap()
   |              ^^^^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the anonymous lifetime defined here...
  --> src/ir/foo.rs:23:14
   |
23 |     fn index(&self, _index: usize) -> &Self::Output {
   |              ^^^^^
note: ...so that reference does not outlive borrowed content
  --> src/ir/foo.rs:24:9
   |
24 |         self.get_bar(_index).unwrap()
   |         ^^^^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime `'ctx` as defined here...
  --> src/ir/foo.rs:20:7
   |
20 | impl <'ctx> Index<usize> for Foo<'ctx> {
   |       ^^^^
note: ...so that the types are compatible
  --> src/ir/foo.rs:23:53
   |
23 |       fn index(&self, _index: usize) -> &Self::Output {
   |  _____________________________________________________^
24 | |         self.get_bar(_index).unwrap()
25 | |     }
   | |_____^
   = note: expected `<Foo<'ctx> as Index<usize>>`
              found `<Foo<'_> as Index<usize>>`
```

(I see a few similar questions on SO but they all seem to differ in the particulars, namely that the Output type has a lifetime parameter).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to that the rust compiler cannot infer proper lifetimes when there are multiple elided lifetimes. The rust compiler can only take the omitted lifetimes as a same lifetime `'_`.

The inferred signature of the function `get_bar` is actually:

```
pub fn get_bar<'_>(self: &'_ Foo<'_>, index: usize) -> Option<&'_ Bar<'_>>
```

Note that all `'_` refer to the same lifetime, this is obviously not what we need, because we don't have to keep borrowing the value of some `Bar` during the whole lifetime of `'ctx`.

And, the inferred signature of the function `index` is:

```
fn index<'_>(self: &'_ Foo<'ctx>, _index: usize) -> &'_ Bar<'ctx>
```

Which is more generic than the signature of `get_bar` because it allows the lifetime argument of `'_` to be shorter than `'ctx`, therefore you cannot call `get_bar` within the body of `index`

To make it work, you have to specify an explicit `'ctx`, because the elided lifetime `'_` has to be the lifetime of the borrowed `self`.

```
impl<'ctx> Foo<'ctx> {
    pub fn get_bar(&self, index: usize) -> Option<&Bar<'ctx>> {
        self.bars.get(index)
    }
}
```

And the signature of `get_bar` now turns to be:

```
pub fn get_bar<'_>(self: &'_ Foo<'ctx>, index: usize) -> Option<&'_ Bar<'ctx>>
```

Then the lifetimes in `index` could match the lifetimes in `get_bar`

Comment: Ah, that makes sense thank you! I had been operating under the assumption that the elided lifetime for the return type `Bar` was the same as the anonymous one in `Foo<'_>` but different from the one in the method, but I see how that doesn't really make a ton of sense.